# PHP include that refreshes (now playing information for radio station)

Tags: php, html

I am putting together an online radio station, and I am using Applescript to update my server with the "nowplaying" information that is ultimately coming from iTunes. 
Applescript pushes that information to the server as a .html file. 
That works fine, then I receive the information into my website using this line of php:

```
$fp = fopen ("music/rtl.txt","r"); 
if (!feof($fp) ) 
{ 
   $buffer = fgets($fp, 1024); 
   print "<tr><td align=\"center\"><b>Current Track</b>: $buffer"; 
} 
fclose ($fp);
```

My question is: how do I get this information to udpate automatically? Even though it is updating on the server, it will remain still until I hit refresh on the webpage. 
How do I get this PHP information to refresh itself without having to manually refresh my screen? How can the Current Track information change automatically?

Comment: Use AJAX?  What have you tried?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, it won't allow me to accept any answers. It pops up saying I need a 15 reputation first.

Comment: Madbreaks, I have not tried using Ajax yet. Not really sure where to begin, still a beginner at all this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, on your html page, use a span with an id to indicate the spot where you want the track info to go:

```
//html page
<tr><td align="center"><b>Current Track</b>: <span id="currentTrack"></span>";
```

Then, assuming jquery is cool, use the `ajax` function inside a custom function, then use `setInterval` to run it every 5 seconds:

```
//script page (using jquery)
$(function(){

    setInterval(refreshTrack,5000); //  5 SECONDS

    function refreshTrack() {
        $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'ajax.php',
                success: function(txt) {
                    $('#currentTrack').text(txt);
                }
            });
    }
});
```

And of course, your ajax page will look pretty much like what you've got, except take away the html markup, because what it spits out will go between the `<span>` tags:

```
// ajax.php
$fp = fopen ("music/rtl.txt","r"); 
if (!feof($fp) ) 
{ 
   $buffer = fgets($fp, 1024); 
   echo $buffer; 
}
```

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks so much!
So I am assuming that AJAX is used for events to be updated on screen without refreshing the page? Such as forms?

Comment: AJAX uses client-side javascript to send data to the server that could normally only be sent be refreshing the page (or clicking a link). a requst is made behind the scenes and you don't see it, but the server does it's thing and sends it's output back to the javascript, which changes the page in the user's browser. For a more technical explanation see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Comment: Excellent. I really wish I could 1+ this post, but I don't have the credentials on this site yet. Still new.

Comment: @JonathanSafa You are allowed to accept answers from the time you are born on S.O.  In fact, accepting the answer gives you some necessary rep to vote up other questions. Look for the outline of the checkmark and click it. It should turn green, right?